# Float object is not iterable even though I'm using a range

Tags: python, function, for-loop, range

I'm trying to write a function that calculates binomial probabilities (I'm aware that scipy.stats.binom exists but this I can't use that). Here's what I have gotten:

```
import math

def binomial(l,u,n,p):
    for i in range(l,u):
        f=sum(math.comb(n,i)*(p**i)*(1-p)**(n-i))
    return(f)
```

However, when I test it out with binomial(0,5,10,0.25), I get an error message 'TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable'. To my knowledge, this occurs a lot  when if I forgot to use a range for the loop but I did in this case. Any hints why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the use of `sum`. You are passing a float to `sum`. To get the expected output you need to store the value of `math.comb(n,i)*(p**i)*(1-p)**(n-i)` for each loop.

Example:

```
def binomial(l,u,n,p):
    values = []
    for i in range(l,u):
        values.append(math.comb(n,i)*(p**i)*(1-p)**(n-i))
    return sum(values)
```

or with list comprehension:

```
def binomial(l,u,n,p):
    values = [math.comb(n,i)*(p**i)*(1-p)**(n-i) for i in range(l,u)]
    return sum(values)
```

Comment: Or just put the generator in the argument to `sum()`